# regex \s not honored in sed via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sed

I'm trying to edit a remote file in a bash script via ssh:

The file looks like this:

```
{
  "lastqueueid" : "7865904306",
  "jobqueuetimestamp" : "1506489874000",
  "mincleanstartsegment" : "7516101",
  "lastposition" : "519949359362951172",
  "maxsegment" : "7566259"
}
```

I'm trying to use sed to change the `"lastqueueid"` from `7865904306` to `$LATEST_QUEUE`. So I tried...

```
ssh user@host sed \
    "s@"lastqueueid"\s\:\s\"[0-9]+\"@"lastqueueid"\s\:\s"$LATEST_QUEUE"@g" \
    /file.json
```

sed won't throw an error, but it will not make a substitution either. It seems that its not honoring `\s` as a whitespace. If I remove `\s` and add a literal space instead, I get the dreaded `` unterminated `s' command `` error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have difficulties to decrypt your command. maybe you want to describe you problem more clearly, and what do you mean by "not making the substitution".

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr The problem is clear as crystal. "not making the substitution" means not succeeding "changing the lastqueueid from 7865904306 to $LATEST_QUEUE.

Comment: if that's the exact command you ran, your quotes are wrong.

Comment: @OP Is $LATEST_QUEUE set? And if it is, *where* did you set it?

Comment: The shell is interpreting \s because it is in double quotes before see ever gets the command. They are becoming literal s.  It may be helpful to set -x in the shell to see more about what it is doing.

Comment: Well, '\' is a special character for the shell also... so you have to check what program is actually consuming it.  As you have written, all the \ are consumed by the shell.... so you have to double them to be interpreted by `sed(1)`

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to write such a complicated command which ssh is happy with:

```
[STEP 101] # ssh 127.0.0.1 cat tmp/file.json
{
  "lastqueueid" : "7865904306",
  "jobqueuetimestamp" : "1506489874000",
  "mincleanstartsegment" : "7516101",
  "lastposition" : "519949359362951172",
  "maxsegment" : "7566259"
}
[STEP 102] # LATEST_QUEUE=1111111111
[STEP 103] # ssh 127.0.0.1 sed -Ee \''s@^(\s*"lastqueueid"\s*:\s*)"[0-9]+"@\1"'\'$LATEST_QUEUE\''"@'\' tmp/file.json
{
  "lastqueueid" : "1111111111",
  "jobqueuetimestamp" : "1506489874000",
  "mincleanstartsegment" : "7516101",
  "lastposition" : "519949359362951172",
  "maxsegment" : "7566259"
}
[STEP 104] #
```

For [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (or [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh)?), follow these steps to generate a command string which can be safely passed to ssh:

1. Make a command and verify it can be run correctly on the local system. For example:

   ```
   [STEP 201] # echo 11 22 33 | sed -e 's/\s/_/g'
   11_22_33
   [STEP 202] #
   ```
2. Save the command into a file:

   ```
   [STEP 202] # cat cmdfile
   echo 11 22 33 | sed -e 's/\s/_/g'
   [STEP 203] #
   ```
3. Use `printf %q` to generate the command string to pass to ssh:

   ```
   [STEP 203] # sshcmd=$( printf '%q' "$(< cmdfile)" )  # double quoted
   [STEP 204] # printf '%s\n' "$sshcmd"                 # dobule quoted
   echo\ 11\ 22\ 33\ \|\ sed\ -e\ \'s/\\s/_/g\'
   [STEP 205] #
   ```
4. Pass the cmdstring to ssh using `eval` or `bash -c`:

   ```
   [STEP 205] # ssh localhost eval "$sshcmd"     # double quoted
   11_22_33
   [STEP 206] # ssh localhost bash -c "$sshcmd"  # double quoted
   11_22_33
   [STEP 207] #
   ```

With **Bash 4.4+** we can also use the `%{var@Q}` syntax which produces **shorter and more human-readable** output:

```
[STEP 300] # echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.12(2)-release
[STEP 301] # sshcmd=$(<cmdfile)
[STEP 302] # printf '%s\n' "$sshcmd"
echo 11 22 33 | sed -e 's/\s/_/g'
[STEP 303] # sshcmd=${sshcmd@Q}
[STEP 304] # printf '%s\n' "$sshcmd"
'echo 11 22 33 | sed -e '\''s/\s/_/g'\'''
[STEP 305] # ssh 127.0.0.1 eval "$sshcmd"
11_22_33
[STEP 306] # ssh 127.0.0.1 bash -c "$sshcmd"
11_22_33
[STEP 307] #
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Can you help me understand why it works? I get most of it, but I'm not sure why you had to add \' at the beginning and the end, and not sure why it was necessary to use a ^( at the very beginning. Also, doesn't doing /1 just tell sed to only make 1 substitution? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `^` is special for the bourne shell.... is an old version for the piping character `|`, so it must be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three problems here:

1. Many versions of `sed` don't understand `\s` -- that's a perl thing. There are three main variants of regular expression syntax you'll run into on unix/linux systems: [basic (BRE), extended (ERE), and perl-compatible (PCRE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards). `sed` uses BRE by default, but can be told to use ERE syntax with the `-r` or `-E` option (depending on the version of `sed` you have). The equivalent of `\s` in BRE and ERE syntax is `[[:space:]]`.

   Another problem is that `+` (as in `[0-9]+`) isn't recognized in BRE syntax. Just use `[0-9][0-9]*`. Oh, and you don't need to escape `:` in any RE syntax.
2. Quotes don't nest. When you use `"s@"lastqueueid"\s...`, the shell treats `"s@"` as a quoted string, `lastqueueid` as an unquoted string, `"\s...` as the beginning of another quoted string, etc. You need the inner quotes to be treated as part of the string rather than delimiters around (part of) it (i.e. you need literal, rather than syntactic, quotes). One way to do this is to escape the quotes that should be literal (`"s@\"lastqueueid\"\s...`), another is to use a different kind of quotes (single vs double) for the outer quotes (`'s@"lastqueueid"\s...'` -- but `$variable` won't be expanded in single-quotes).

   But there's another complication, because...
3. Since this command is being passed over `ssh`, it goes through the whole process of shell parsing and quote/escape interpretation and removal *twice*, once on the local computer and then again by the shell on the remote computer. This means that you need quotes around quotes around quotes (the first to be interpreted and removed by the local shell, the second to be interpreted and removed by the remote shell, and the third to be treated as part of the pattern to match). This gets messy.

   BTW, this third problem is why you're getting the "unterminated 's' command" error when you use actual spaces -- by the time it gets to the remote shell, the command looks like this:

   ```
   sed s@lastqueueid : '[0-9]+@lastqueueid' : 123456789@g /file.json
   ```

   ... so `sed` tries to execute `s@lastqueueid` as the command (with all the rest being filenames), and can't parse it.

So, what to do? It looks to m like the simplest quoting strategy will be to use double-quotes around single-quotes around escaped double-quotes. Something like this:

```
"'s@\"lastqueueid\" : \"[0-9][0-9]*\"@\"lastqueueid\" : \"$LATEST_QUEUE\"@g'"
```

After being parsed by the local shell, `ssh` receives (and passes to the remote shell) something like this:

```
's@"lastqueueid" : "[0-9][0-9]*"@"lastqueueid" : "123456789"@g'
```

...the remote shell removes the single-quotes and `sed` gets this:

```
s@"lastqueueid" : "[0-9][0-9]*"@"lastqueueid" : "123456789"@g
```

...which is what you want.

Well, maybe. I see a couple of other possible problems. First, is the file actually /file.json (i.e. at the root of the remote filesystem)? If not, fix the path. Second, are you trying to replace the remote file with the edited version? By default, `sed` just prints out the edited version, it doesn't save it. To do an in-place edit, use `-i.bak` (where ".bak" is the file extension to save a pre-edit backup under).

Comment: Thanks! This worked and actually makes the most sense to me of the solutions provided so far.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for pointing that out; I've modified my answer accordingly. I did test GNU sed, but apparently the linux system I tested on has a really old version (4.1.2), and this feature's been added sometime since then.